# Using a function that returns a type as a type hint

Tags: python, types, fastapi

I am building a FastAPI application where I make use of [callable instance dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/?h=dependencies#a-callable-instance). I use these dependencies to make authorization decisions in the application, and I pass the permissions I want to enforce when creating the class instance.

To make the code more concise I followed FastAPI's documentation's suggestion of [reusing dependencies by using Annotated](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/?h=dependencies#share-annotated-dependencies) type aliases stored in variables. However, I instead use a lambda function that accepts the `required_permissions` parameter and creates the right dependency.

Here's a simplified example of the dependency and lambda:

```py
class AuthorizationDependency():
    def __init__(self, required_permissions: list[str]):
        self.required_permissions

    def __call__(self, user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_user)]) -> User:
        if user.has_permissions(required_permissions):
            return user
        raise Exception()


Authorization = lambda required_permissions: Annotated[
    User,
    Depends(AuthorizationDependency(required_permissions),
]
```

And here's how I then use it in my code:

```
@router.get(
    path="/my_things",
)
async def get_things(
    user: Authorization(
        required_permissions=["read:things"]
    ),
):
    return user.things
```

This works just fine, **except**... The type of the `user` parameter is detected as `Any`, when it would be useful for me to have correct type hints.

This seems to be caused by the lambda function, since if I instead use Annotated in a variable directly, like so:

```
AuthorizeForThings = Annotated[
    User,
    Depends(AuthorizationDependency(["read:things"]),
]

@router.get(
    path="/my_things",
)
async def get_things(
    user: AuthorizeForThings,
):
    return user.things
```

The code analysis infers the right type for `user`. Mind you that Pylance can tell that the lambda returns a `type[User]`, it just doesn't use that information as the type hint, unfortunately.

Any idea on how I can make the type hint work, or am I out of luck because I am already wrapping the real type in so much abstraction?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to annotate the lambda function and not return an Annotated class from the function? `Authorization = Annotated[User, Depends(AuthorizationDependency(required_permissions)]` (i.e. you're saying that the lambda returns a User explicitly, not that the lambda returns something that has been annotated)

Comment: @MatsLindh do you mean `Authorization = Annotated[User, lambda required_permissions: Depends(AuthorizationDependency(required_permissions)`?

I can't use it as I do in the endpoints, however, since Authorization(required_permissions) attempts to instantiate a User.